# exposing only a small subset of functions from a header

Tags: c

I have a 
"header file" (file1.h) that has multiple function prototypes declaration and a 
"C file"(file1.c) that has associated function definitions.

I want to expose only particular functions prototypes from the "header file" (file1.h) to another "C file" (file2.c) without exposing the rest of the functions.

Question1: What is the best way to do this? 
Options: Created another header that has the required functions only that is included in (file2.c)

Question2 & 3: When would `extern` come in handy? 
I have seen usage of `extern` in some functions in header files while other functions don't use the keyword. Whats the idea?

Comment: Please tell me why would it be a problem what all prototypes are not exposed

Comment: Short advice: don't. At link time, the functions **will** be *exposed* anyway. So: you can hide the names in your header from the compiler, but you cannot hide the names in the object file from the linker.

Comment: @Ed Heal I don't want the second file (file2.c) to be able to  access the other functions in (file1.c). In general, I don't have any idea why exposing all the headers in my project by including then in all C files in my project would affect my code.

Comment: Use the `static` keyword for functions you don't want to be used outside the C file.

Comment: @wildplasser Do you mean that if i expose the same function prototypes from (file1.h) in another header file (file2,h) and include in file2.c the object files will still have all functions exposed. IMO, the issue would be that there are 2 copies of the same function between the 2 headers and if I am using the function for Getter purposes it wont get the correct values.

Comment: Prototypes (maybe in header files) are there to inform the compiler about functions that it cannot *see*, so it can generate correct code when *calling* them. At the linking stage, these names are *actually* resolved. (the linker uses the symbol tables in the object files)

Answer (score 3):

Easy. For "public" function prototypes/declarations, put them in the `.h` file.

**`func.h`**

---

```
int func1(void);
int func2(int i);
```

For the functions you don't want exposed, just put them in the `.c` file.

**`func.c`**

---

```
/* Function prototypes. */
static int func3(void);

/* Function definitions. */
int func1(void) {
    func3();
    return 0;
}

int func2(int i) {
    func3();
    return (i + i);
}

static int func3(void) {
    return 42;
}
```

Next, depending on your compiler, setup an [exported symbol whitelist](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) (ie: `gcc hidden attributes`, for example, on Linux), to limit what symbols are exported.

Finally, `strip` the final binary after it has been compiled (ie: `strip --strip-unneeded myfile.so`), and you're all set. Even if the user knows the API in use, your "private" symbols could only be directly accessed via non-portable hacks.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

One common way to expose only some functions in the public API (this is how the Motif GUI libraries do it) is to put prototypes for the publicly available functions in MyThing.h, then put the rest in MyThingI.h, which #includes MyThing.h, and your .c file includes MyThingI.h (The I is for Internal). That way, your own code can have multiple files that include the I.h file, while the public .h files delivered with your library only include the .h file.

All of the prototypes in the .h file should use the "extern" keyword.